# How to set the path to cache files of gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I started to use IntelliJ IDE to make a java program recently.
I need to use gradle build tools but I am in trouble at building code.

One of the problems is that gradle tried to make its working folder outside my project folder.

In the previous project I made with grade, gradle automatically made a directory, .gradle under the project root directory like,

```
(project root directory)/.gradle
```

But now, it tries to make it under another directory like,

```
(USER_HOME)\Desktop\(PROJECT_NAME)\(PROJECT_NAME)\.gradle
```

I found the following debug message,

```
11:43:48.167 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildLogger] Current dir: C:(USER_HOME)\Desktop\(PROJECT_NAME)\(PROJECT_NAME)
```

So, it seems gradle set the starting directory of building code as C:(USER_HOME)\Desktop(PROJECT_NAME)(PROJECT_NAME)

and it makes .gradle folder under it.

How can I change the starting directory to (project root directory) in gradle?
Please let me know it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle by default puts this cache in the folder where file `settings.gradle` is.

Is is not clear what changes this behavior in your case. Some possibilities:

- You added another `settings.gradle` file, the folder can change.
- You modified you [GRADLE_USER_HOME or GRADLE_OPTS variables](http://mrhaki.blogspot.jp/2010/09/gradle-goodness-changing-gradle-user.html)

Comment: Thank you a lot for letting me know it. Yes. I did not make settings.gradle in the new project. I will remake my project. By the way how can I set values of GRADLE_USER_HOME and GRADLE_OPTS? Are they environment variables?

Comment: yes, they are environment variables. follow the links, search on Google.